# Parse Json Data in node JS

Tags: node.js, firebase

I have data from firebase which looks like it is in JSON format. I want to get ordered_item_cost and other values from this data. Please help me with this.
this is my data:

```
 { '-LaAHp3jEK70tWB01-Go':
   { ordered_item_cost: '15',
     ordered_item_name: 'bourban-biscuits',
     ordered_item_quantity: '1',
     ordered_item_total_cost: 15,
     ordered_time: '3/17/2019, 4:26:05 PM' },
  '-LaAHsjSCNqz8VbxeMgp':
   { ordered_item_cost: '5',
     ordered_item_name: 'dark fantasy',
     ordered_item_quantity: '1',
     ordered_item_total_cost: 5,
     ordered_time: '3/17/2019, 4:26:20 PM' } }
```

Comment: Sure thing. What have you tried so far? What do you expect to get out of the data?

Comment: i want to get ordered_item_cost from the data. I tried looping the data but did'nt get any output @AKX

Comment: Please share the code that you used to loop over the data. It is important to share what you have done to come up with an appropriate answer

Comment: I guess you want to re-shape this data from HashTable to List. If so you can use `Object.values(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got peculiar keys of your object. Assuming they are random keys and you probably do not know these keys beforehands, so you should push them to array and operate your object values with these parsed array keys.

What you may want to do

```
    var x =
    {
        '-LaAHp3jEK70tWB01-Go':

            { ordered_item_cost: '15',
                ordered_item_name: 'bourban-biscuits',
                ordered_item_quantity: '1',
                ordered_item_total_cost: 15,
                ordered_time: '3/17/2019, 4:26:05 PM' },
        '-LaAHsjSCNqz8VbxeMgp':
            { ordered_item_cost: '5',
                ordered_item_name: 'dark fantasy',
                ordered_item_quantity: '1',
                ordered_item_total_cost: 5,
                ordered_time: '3/17/2019, 4:26:20 PM' }
    }

var arr=[]
for (var y in x) {
    arr.push(y);
}

for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    console.log(x[arr[i]].ordered_item_cost)
}
```

With this logic in mind you could also use .map, .filter or .reduce built ins to operate your object.

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects in JS are key-value pairs, so to access the values, you need to use the keys. For example, if you had a variable called data used to store the JSON, you could access the values by doing something like this:

```
data = 
{ '-LaAHp3jEK70tWB01-Go':
   { ordered_item_cost: '15',
     ordered_item_name: 'bourban-biscuits',
     ordered_item_quantity: '1',
     ordered_item_total_cost: 15,
     ordered_time: '3/17/2019, 4:26:05 PM' },
  '-LaAHsjSCNqz8VbxeMgp':
   { ordered_item_cost: '5',
     ordered_item_name: 'dark fantasy',
     ordered_item_quantity: '1',
     ordered_item_total_cost: 5,
     ordered_time: '3/17/2019, 4:26:20 PM' } 
}

item_cost = data['-LaAHsjSCNqz8VbxeMgp']['ordered_item_cost'] // Would get you a value of 5
```